# How to show a solution is global

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I am seeking for methods ensuring there exists at least a global solution of the ODE
$X'(t) = F(t,X(t))$, with
$$F :~ ]-1,\infty[ \times ]1,\infty[ \times \mathbb{R} \longmapsto \mathbb{R}^2$$
a certain function I can specify. I am especially interested in the case $+ \infty$ and I found that the characterization of maximal solutions yields
$$
\sup(I) = + \infty~~or~~\lim_{\sup(I)} x_1 = 1
$$
where $I$ is the definition intervall of the maximal solution $X$. This does not helps me that much and I would appreciate a method ensuring $\sup(I) = + \infty$ in this kind of domain.

Comment: If $F$ is continuous and if $F$ is Lipschitz in the second argument with Lipschitz constant indepent of $t$, then you can apply the (global) Picard-Lindelöf theorem, which gives you existence on every closed inteval $I\subset (-1,\infty)$ and thus globally.

Comment: Thank you @dennis_s for this answer, I think the space domain has to be the whole space for the global Picard-Lindelöf theorem to apply, isn't it ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the whole space'? The term global in Picard-Lindelöf refers to the existence of a solution on the whole (closed) interval you want to apply it to.

Comment: In the french Wikipedia (I am french) it is told the global result applies in the case $\Omega = I \times \mathbb{R}^d$ so I thought I had to provide this hypothesis to apply the global result. More consistent references confirm the result you stated in your first comment and which I wasn't sure about. Unfortunately I know that $\sup \partial_x |F(t,x)| = \infty$ when some parameter (hidden here) is small.

Comment: If the parameter is independent of $(t,x)$ then you can apply global PL when it is big and need to check the 'singular' case more directly.
If by parameter you mean something depending on $t$ or $x$ then I need to ask if $F$ as in the description really maps to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Because then I would understand it that way, that $F$ blows up in finite time (assuming $F$ is differentiable), precisely at that time where its spacial derivative explodes. Otherwise if $F$ is differentiable and mapping to $\mathbb{R}^2$ then that supremum is taken only at the boundary $\{-1,\infty\}$ which is fine.

Comment: My parameter is independent of $(t,x)$ and that is why I was seeking for a way to avoid the direct investigation. Thanks you for yout time and explanations.